# how to get total number of machines using composition

Tags: java, composition

how would I get total number of machines using composition ? I was thinking something like this...but I am getting error `The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) int, AssemblyLine`

```
private List<AssemblyLine> machines = new ArrayList<AssemblyLine>();

 public int getMachine(){

     int total= 0;

     for (AssemblyLine machine : machines) {

         total = total + machine;


     }
     return total;

 }
```

Comment: What would it mean to add an `AssemblyLine` to an `int`?

Comment: Is there a `getNumMachines()` method in `AssemblyLine`?  Call it.

Comment: @rgettman i'll do total += machine.getNumMachines(); ...thanks